datarangepicker on input loaded by ajax
I have input witch attached datarangepicker (https://www.daterangepicker.com):
<div id = "content"><input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "fdata">
...
</div>

and
$('#fdata').daterangepicker({
    locale: {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    }
});

After I select the dates, ajax send them to the php script, and receive some html and load it into #container. In this received html is the same input with selected dadates:
<input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "fdata" value = "selected dates">

Now I want to attach daterangepicker to this new input, but I dont know how to do this.

Does this replace the original HTML? If not, you'll have duplicate IDs, which is not allowed.

Anyway, you attach the daterangepicker the same way. After you call $("#content").html(response) you do $("#fdata").daterangepicker(...)

Yest, the response replace original html, and there is only one id #fdata.

Then just re-add the picker after you add the HTML.

If you're using $("#content").load(), do it in the callback function.

I cant, bedause I use $("#content").load() several times and only ones I need datarangepicker.

you can use an if statement to make it conditional.

If you only need it when #fdata has class="dates", you can use $("#fdata.dates").daterangepicker(...). If it doesn't have the class, it won't do anything.

I will do it, thanks.
